# Isolated three level pwm LTSPICE

Tags: ltspice, level-shifting

I am doing a simulation on LTSpice of a three level ANPC. The ground is connected to the neutral point (i.e in the middle point of the DC input) and the gate drivers are isolated by using a DC DC converter (so the voltage is floating). The thing is that I need to gate the transistors and I have the modulation done with signals that go from 0 to 5V.

I did this signals by using BV sources connected to the common ground: one carrier that goes from 0 to 0.5, another that goes from 0.5 V to 1V and the modulating sine in the middle.

How can I impose the PWM to the input of the gate driver? How should I shift the signals to the source level of the transistors?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I normally cheat with the e-function. Set gain to 1 and it will provide indefinite speed and isolation.

Comment: See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372155/how-to-fix-this-ltspice-error/372170#372170) for a possible solution to your case, and to get an idea on a simplified way to simulate what you want, faster.

Answer (score 1):

With a bv source you can use [math equations](http://ltwiki.org/?title=B_sources_(complete_reference)), so just for simulations take if you want to stimulate a combination of signals you could do something like this:

```
bv=V(pwm)*V(gatesignal)+V(whatever)
```

Where pwm, gatesignal and whatever are net names. If you want to reference a current you can use I(netname)

If you want to physically realize this system you'll have to do it with analog multipliers and summing op amps