# How can i get a second PMW signal that ranges from -7V to 0V for this H bridge circuit?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, motor, ltspice, h-bridge

This is the circuit i built.
[image: Circuit]

The data sheet for U1 and U2: https://www.vishay.com/docs/83666/sfh610a.pdf

Currently when i run the circuit and place the curser on the right side of V1 this is the result i'm getting however i need a second PMW signal that ranges from -7V to 0V.

[image: Result]

Comment: I recommend that you use proper MOSFET and opto-isolator symbols rather than boxes. It's much easier to see the *schema* of your circuit and spot PMOS and NMOS device errors, etc. If you are interested, [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics) is well worth a read.

Comment: My eyes hurt looking at your schematic, so [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/372170/95619) is something that may serve as inspiration, because it looks like you're driving the transitors wrong. Also, I don't know what the drivers have inside, but the sources are floating (they need a ground reference).